# Solspace FreeForm assign notifications recipient in entry

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

I've got a client who would like to be able to assign a notification recipient for each entry where a form appears. I would imagine that a new form needs to be created for each recipient, but is there a way to take the form handle, add it to an entry then output that form on a page? Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly but why don't you make use of the [Freeform Forms Field](https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/fieldtypes/) if you want to attach a form per entry.

```
{% if entry.myFreeformfieldname is defined and entry.myFreeformfieldname is not empty %}
    <h3>{{ entry.myFreeformfieldname.name }}</h3>
    {{ entry.myFreeformfieldname.render() }}
{% endif %}
```